# Convert in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
veri=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/VERİLER/titanic.csv",sep=";")
-------------------------------
veri.dtypes
pclass         int64
survived       int64
name          object
sex           object
age           object
sibsp          int64
parch          int64
ticket        object
fare          object
cabin         object
embarked      object
boat          object
body         float64
home.dest     object
dtype: object
---------------------------
veri["age"].plot.hist()
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

hi guys i know to make convert process but i couldnt do it.
How can i do ?

Comment: mosc9575
now when i run "veri["age"] = veri["age"].astype(float)", out is "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.9167' " i confused

Comment: Olasimbo Arigbabu,it work but age values are not displayed i dont know why

Comment: Thank u guys i did it, my data have little bit string expression and i delete it because string that not including number convert to float and integer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.astype` for simple conversion

```py
veri['age'] = veri['age'].astype(int)
```

But if you need a preprocessing, you can use `pd.Series.map`

For example, if you want to remove word "years" in the `age` column before converting

```py
veri['age'] = veri['age'].map(lambda x: int(x.replace('years', '')))
```